# What neon assembly code to combine two vectors into long vector?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

ARM Neon intrinsic vcombine_s16 combinese two vectors into one long vector. What is its assembly code?

Answer (score 3):

```
int16x8_t vcombine_s16 (int16x4_t, int16x4_t)
```

doesn't have a direct matching instruction, it is a way to treat two dual registers as a quad register and provide type safety in C. You would do that in assembly implicitly by just calling dual or quad registers whenever it is required to. See diagram below for possible usages of NEON register bank.

One can see `gcc`'s [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) for intrinsics.

For how this would be implemented in assembly, you can still utilize gcc

```
#include "arm_neon.h"

int16x8_t c(int16x4_t a, int16x4_t b) {
  return vcombine_s16(b, a);
}
```

turns into

```
c(__simd64_int16_t, __simd64_int16_t):
    vswp    d1, d0
    bx  lr
```

I've actually generated this [online](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%5C%22arm_neon.h%5C%22%5Cn%5Cnint16x8_t%20c(int16x4_t%20a%2C%20int16x4_t%20b)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20vcombine_s16(b%2C%20a)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Farm-linux-gnueabi-g%2B%2B-4.6%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22%20-mfpu%3Dneon%20-O2%20-mfloat-abi%3Dhard%22%7D%5D%7D).

So at the end I think this boils to if registers are adjacent then they are already combined, if not you can just use `vmov` or `vswp`.

See this [arm documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s03s02.html) about how `neon` registers laid and referred.

[image]